# Sort Interface list C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a Interface list by date but i cant figure it out.

```
var agencyList = new List<INewsItemBE>();

var item = new News1BE();
//add items
agencyList.Add(item)

var item = new News2BE();
//add items
agencyList.Add(item);
```

After the items is added I want to sort the `agencyList` by date with something like this but I cant get it to work.

```
agencyList.Sort(delegate (News1BE c1, News1BE c2) { return c1.PublishDate.CompareTo(c2.PublishDate); });

agencyList.Sort(delegate (News1BE a, News1BE b) => a.PublishDate.CompareTo(b.PublishDate));
agencyList = agencyList.OrderBy(x => cant find anything at x.).ToList();
```

Comment: The list is correct I get a list with booth items

Comment: Does the `INewsItemBE` interface contain a property called `PublishDate`? because you said you can't find anything at `x`. If not, then either add the property to the interface, or change your list from `List<INewsItemBE>` to `List<New1BE>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

var ordered = agencyList.OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate);
```

Or if you need it descending:

```
var orderedDesc = agencyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate);
```

if you need the list in the original variable again, you can call `.ToList()`:

```
agencyList = agencyList.OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate).ToList();
```

---

Of if LINQ is not working for you (or you wish the best performance and thus decline the overhead brought by LINQ), you can use the `.Sort` method you were trying:

```
agencyList.Sort((item1, item2) => item1.PublishDate.CompareTo(item2.PublishDate));
```

Comment: If you want to sort the original list, you should use `List.Sort()` to sort it, not Linq, otherwise you'll be creating two new lists pointlessly (one for Linq to sort and another for the `ToList()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson or he could assign the query to the original list : `agencyList = agencyList.OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate).ToList();`

Comment: .@MatthewWatson The problem is that agencyList.OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate) dont work cant find binding properties to x.

Comment: @Patte have you added the `using System.Linq`?

Comment: @SynerCoder yes

Comment: @Patte updated with correct implementation of the `.Sort` method you were trying.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I mostly don't care about the extra allocated Lists, the overhead is minimal. But I added the correct implementation of the `.Sort` method. Just in case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try SortedList instead of List, so it will be automatically sorted when you add items.

Define your classes/interfaces:

```
interface INews1BE
{
    DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}

class News1BE : INews1BE
{
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Define comparer for DateTime:

```
class DateTimeAscendingComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
{
    public int Compare(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Now create comparer and sorted list passing comparer to the SortedList constructor:

```
var comparer = new DateTimeAscendingComparer();
var sortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, INews1BE>(comparer);
```

Add some items and check the results:

```
var item1 = new News1BE() 
{
    PublishedDate = DateTime.Now
};

var item2 = new News1BE()
{
    PublishedDate = item1.PublishedDate.AddSeconds(-30)
};

sortedList.Add(item1.PublishedDate, item1);

//item2 goes before item1
sortedList.Add(item2.PublishedDate, item2);

foreach(var x in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
}
```

You can also access your object through Value:

```
foreach (var x in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Value.PublishedDate);
}
```

Or you can iterate over Values to get immediate access to your INews1BE object:

```
foreach(var x in sortedList.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.PublishedDate);
}
```

Actually you don't have to define comparer for DateTime if you just care about ascending order - this is the default behavior, so you can just create SortedList without passing comparer to the constructor:

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, INews1BE>();
```

But if you need Descending order just switch DateTime `a` with DateTime `b` when comparing:

```
class DateTimeDescendingComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
{
    public int Compare(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        return b.CompareTo(a);
    }
}
```